# Adding PlaceAutocompleteFragment to fragment throws error

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-places-api

I have implemented PlaceAutocompleteFragment in activity and is working successfuly. But how to implement the same in fragment in android?
I have implemented placeautocomplete fragment like this

```
 PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment1 = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment1);
```

Error I am getting is

> Incovertible types;cannot cast 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' to com.google.android.gms.location.PlaceAutocompleteFragment '.

XML LAYOUT IS

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_background"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            card_view:contentPadding="0dp">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Place"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
            />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your xml layout.

Comment: @Amit Nair see my answer below.

Comment: Can you post the full code here or git-hub and post a link. I'm working on the same [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42549497/java-null-pointer-exception-on-google-places-fragment/42549726?noredirect=1#comment72235739_42549726) and running into numerous errors @Amit Nair

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use `getActivity()` like this way.

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment1  = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment1);
```

Comment: @AmitNair glad to help you.

Comment: @AhmedWagdi use it inside fragment class. If you are not in Activity or fragment then pass the context to that class and use like this   context.getFragmentManager()

Answer (score 24):

1. Change **SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment** instead of <strike>PlaceAutocompleteFragment</strike> in your layout xml

```
   fragment 
    android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment"                          
    android:layout_width="match_parent"                        
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
```

2. Change **getChildFragmentManager()** instead of <strike>getFragmentManager()</strike>  and use **SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment** instead of <strike>PlaceAutocompleteFragment</strike> in your java file,.

   ```
    SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
   ```

Comment: This is the method that should be used when dealing with a nested fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution in Kotlin. This is specifically for if you want to launch the autocomplete fragment while being in a fragment.

```
val autocompleteFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_support_fragment) as AutocompleteSupportFragment?
```

```xml
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/autocomplete_support_fragment"
    android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following in your XML layout file:

```
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
 />
```

Note the full classname and id, your id don't match. (place_autocomplete_fragment1)

Answer (score 0):

The fragment id should be `android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment1"`

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another valid reason of this error is that you must be extending your `Fragment` class from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and casting it to `PlaceAutoCompleteFragment` which extends `Fragment` class from `com.google.android.gms.location.PlaceAutocompleteFragment`.
To avoid this you should/can use `SupportPlaceAutoCompleteFragment` instead of you are using.

```
SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment1 = (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment1);
```

Using this your autocomplete widget will also work on the lower version devices.