# How to use AutocompleteSupportFragment inside a fragment

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am using places api and dependency

```
  implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
```

I want to add an 
AutocompleteSupportFragment in a fragment. 
Please help me where should I place the code in the fragment. I have tried on these methods

```
1. onCreate()
2. onCreateView()
3. onViewCreated()
4. onActivityCreated()
```

But it gives null object reference error. I have tried it with an activity, it works fine.

public class 
MyActivity extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{

```
    AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteSupportFragment;


    public ConsumerBookingMapFragment(){ }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_consumer_booking_map,container,false);
    return mView;

}

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mLastKnownLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_LOCATION);
            mCameraPosition = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION);
        }
        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());
        mMapView = mView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        if(mMapView != null){
            mMapView.onCreate(null);
            mMapView.onResume();
            mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Comment: Post your code,what you have tried till now  !

Comment: This is my code, guide me where should I initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996672/adding-placeautocompletefragment-to-fragment-throws-error) out !

Comment: Thank you, I found the solution.

Comment: @SamiNoorKhan so what is the solution? Why don't you share it?

Comment: @SamiNoorKhan, why not sharing the solution ?

Answer (score 4):

This is a working solution.

```
  AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
                    getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);
```

Use **getChildFragmentManager()** instead of **getSupportFragmentManager()/getFragmentManager()**

Answer (score 0):

It is answered in this post...

[Google Places API AutocompleteSupportFragment Null pointer Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55170265/google-places-api-autocompletesupportfragment-null-pointer-exception)

Things to remember..

Make sure you use  component in your layout xml file. (Not FrameLayout)
Also use the android:name as shown below..

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/autoCompleteFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment" />
```

And follow the steps in the answer